# Spring - CrudRepository is not created

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, h2

The `CrudRepository` bean

```
@Repository
public interface UserDao extends CrudRepository<User, Long>
{
    List<User> findByFirstNameAndLastName(String firstName, String lastName);
}
```

for the `User` resource

```
@Entity
@Table(name="User")
public class User 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    /* --- Getters,setters,default constructor -------*/
}
```

is not created when I start my Spring boot app

```
Field dao in base.package.service.UserService required a bean 
of type 'base.package.dao.UserDao' that could not be found.
```

but the packages are definitely scanned

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages= {"base.package"})
```

I got the strong suspicion that it has to do something with the embedded database `h2` that I am using. I am trying to create the `User` table in `schema.sql`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User (
    id   INTEGER      NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

but as soon as I uncomment `IF NOT EXISTS` it throws an error (table already exists). So this firstly means that spring takes charge of created the schema. But I get the feeling that the table is not recreated because in the `data.sql` script

```
INSERT INTO User (id,first_name,last_name) VALUES (1,'Vincent', 'Vega');
```

I always have to manually increment the `id` on startup otherwise i get a

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.USER(ID)"
```

Here are the jpa properties from `application.properties`

```
# below properties create schema, so schema.sql is redundant
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true  
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.database=H2
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE


spring.datasource.name=testdb
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
```

The reason why I think that the table is never recreated on startup is because I get this error when the app closes

```
2018-02-02 09:27:47.907 INFO  [restartedMain] [StandardService] Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-02-02 09:27:47.907 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1] [WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [MVStore background writer nio:C:/Users/user/testdb.mv.db] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
```

This is followed by the exception that `UserDao` bean is not created.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field dao in base.package.user.service.UserService required a bean of type 'base.package.user.dao.UserDao' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'base.package.user.dao.UserDao' in your configuration.
```

**POM.XML**

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.M5</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
       /* .... */
```

**EDIT**

Here is the `UserService`

```
@Service
public class UserService 
{
    @Autowired private UserDao dao;

    public List<User> findByFirstNameAndLastName(String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        return dao.findByFirstNameAndLastName(firstName, lastName);
    }

    public User save(final User user)
    {
        return dao.save(user);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Now I am getting

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.project.bot.user.User
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:472)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:169)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:107)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:90)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:300)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$3(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:287)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706)
    ... 102 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Have you tried: public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User, Long>

Comment: What does `UserService` look like?

Comment: @rocksteady please see edit

Comment: @MatMat no but it worked yesterday with CrudRepository, I am so confused

Comment: `package` should be the Reserved Field, you need change your package name.

Comment: You talk about the package `base.package.dao.UserDao` but the error message says `required a bean of type 'com.ubs.symphony.bot.user.dao.UserDao'`. Where is `base.package...` relative to `com.ubs...`?

Comment: I am using `base.package` as a placeholder for `com.ubs`.. apologies

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The table not being created should not have any impact on whether the bean is defined or not.

I think the problem you have here is that you are not instatiating your repository beans. Spring Data JPA repository beans are not picked up by component scans since they are only interfaces. The `@Repository` annotation actually does nothing here.

Spring Data JPA repo beans are created dynamically provided you have supplied the `@EnableJpaRepositories` in your configuration.

You may also need to put an @EntityScan to make sure all your @Entity's are recognised by Spring

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages= {"base.package"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("base.package")
@EntityScan("base.package")
```

Comment: @Repository annotation should do something because it includes Component right? So a simple ComponentScan should pick it up

Comment: No because the Spring data repositories are special. They are only interfaces so cannot be defined as `@Components`. Spring data dynamically creates a concrete implementation based on the repositories you define. But it will only make these concrete beans if you have the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation

Comment: @tenticon I edited my post with an answer to your second issue